# pd cut last value does not get labeled

Tags: python, pandas

I was testing the `cut` method in Pandas to convert a continuous variable (age) into discrete bins (age groups). In order to make this method reproducible for any age range, or even for other continuous variables, I wanted to convert `age` to percentages. So I sorted the dataframe in an ascending order, calculated cumulative sum (`cumsum`), which I then converted to `percent cumsum`. Next, I `pd.cut` the percent cumsum column with bins as `[0,20,40,60,80,100]` and add labels too.

The `pd.cut` splits the age variable into 5 bins and labels them correctly, except for the last age value, which has a percent cumsum of 100. I even set the optional `right` argument to `True`, but somehow this last data point still does not get classified to any bin and its label shows `nan`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k'],'Age':np.random.randint(3,26,10)})
df = df.sort_values('Age')
df['CumSum'] = df['Age'].cumsum()
df['Percent_CumSum'] = 100*df.CumSum/df.Age.sum()
df['Buckets'] = pd.cut(df.Percent_CumSum,bins=[0,20,40,60,80,100],\
labels=['p','s','m','l','xl'],right=True)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a sample input/output and show what is going wrong?  Please see [mcve]

Comment: Added more info to the question.

Comment: Your [mcve] work for me, maybe upgrade your pandas version. I am using pandas 0.23.0